# Table name default is Table_s not Tables in laravel 5.5

Tags: database, laravel, filenames

When I use model A16  with eloquent

such as

```
php artisan db:seed
```

or other eloquent

```
$wantdata=A16::all
```

it shows

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Db.A16_s'

I know I can fix with blow :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tablename extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'A16s';
}
```

But how do I  change the Tables for my default habits.
And why I  got A16_s not the A16s? I want to know how to fix it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent
the document write:

> assume the Flight model stores records in the flights table

My laravel 5.5 default model.php write

```
 public function getTable()
    {
        if (! isset($this->table)) {
            return str_replace(
                '\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this)))
            );
        }

        return $this->table;
    }
```

why the default is snake case? how can I change it to the normal xxs name?

Comment: The only way I've been able to get that value is if the model is named `Table_`. Does your model name end in an underscore?

Comment: My model name is A16
The table name he want to find is A16_s not A16s.
I am so confused.

Comment: did you make any changes to the `Model.php` or over riding the `getTable()` method?

Comment: @ab_in I don't change the Model.php and getTable() method but why the default is the snake case?

Comment: @robspin Its a general practise in naming tables that's why `snake_case` is used. you can specify table name by in the model or use something like @ben 's answer

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [`getTable()` definition](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L1178), the table name defined at:

```
        return str_replace(
            '\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this)))
        );
```

It uses snake case and this is the reason why you got 'a16_s' instead of 'a16s'.

You can override the `getTable()` function if you want to have your own version, by inherit a custom model like this:

```
class tablename extends CustomModel
{
    ...
}


class CustomModel extends Model
{
    public function getTable()
    {
        if (! isset($this->table)) {
            // your own implementation here
        }
        return $this->table;
    }
}
```

or just define the `$table` variable or each model.

Comment: I check my Model.php just like you write.
But I don't change the default getTable() function. Why the default is snake case?
And how do I change it to the  A16s default
it's either not the Camel Case so it's what case how can I change it?

Comment: The simple way is to override the `$table` variable. Using snake case because, such as you have `UserRole` Model, the table naming is then `user_roles`.